# Reading package lists... Error!

Tags: downloads

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to synchronize mmap - msync (5: Input/output error)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I get this when trying to install programs and when i do sudo apt-get update it ends up having: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following commands and it worked for me:

```
 sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bad
 sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
 sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the package that cannot be downloaded by scrolling back up after doing sudo apt-get update. Remove the source website from /etc/apt/sources.list.