# How can I fix my broken package manager? "software index is broken"

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-sources

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. How can I fix the following issue?

[image: IMG:]

```
Software index is broken

This is a major failure of your software management system.    
Please check for broken packages with synaptic, check the file  
permissions and correctness of the file '/etc/apt/sources.list' and    
reload the software information with: 'sudo apt-get update' and   
'sudo apt-get install -f'.
```

In addition to this error I'm also still getting the same error in the terminal as I got while trying to install an .rpm package in my previous question: [Restoring system for a crashed installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952659/restoring-system-for-a-crashed-installation). I also got an error message about an obsolete PPA and another xenial repository that can't be authenticated.

I can't install any packages at all. I can't use apt-get, can't use gebi installer, and I can't even open the Synaptic package manager.

Comment: Maybe you can try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/646176/reading-package-lists-error

Comment: @userDepth, I don't know what the file, "/etc/......." should had contained, and the second solution didn't work, Can I reinstall the package manager or something?

Comment: I remembered that sometimes servers take a little extra time to refresh the list archives and during that time this happens. Try using the main server instead and run an apt-get update.

Answer (score 5):

As this error message `Software index is broken. This is a major failure of your software management system.` suggests, there is a major failure of your software management system comprised of several different errors, and these errors need to be individually repaired one error at a time in order to restore your package management to working condition.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: it won't let me do the second step and gives this error: https://pasteboard.co/GIV4hsV.png

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the files from /var/cache/apt/archives/

try this

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*
```

This will remove all the .deb files in archives directory. The above command will also remove the partial directory which is needed by apt, apt-get, etc, to download .deb files before installing them.

Then try these to recreate partial directory in /var/lib/apt/lists/ and in /var/cache/apt/archives/

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo mkdir /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

Check this link for solution
[Software Index is broken](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1804871)

And this for an explanation on package management
[Why are there deb files in /var/cache/apt/archives/?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531978/why-are-there-deb-files-in-var-cache-apt-archives)

Comment: I tried this and the linked page's commands, however, it's still not working. This happened when I was trying to install maya, and this is the error:  https://pasteboard.co/GIV4hsV.png

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pinta/+bug/1607586

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it using

```bash
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/full_name_of_package
```