# Package Manager broken while trying to install missing dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I was trying to update an old software and a friend suggested that my apt was in an older version, so I followed the steps in item 2) of [this link](https://www.stechies.com/aptget-command-not-foundin-linux/). I downloaded the most recent .deb for my architecture (apt_1.9.4ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) and tried installing, which lead to two unmet dependencies, one of which I managed to install without errors (libapt-inst2.0_1.8.4_amd64).

```
$ sudo dpkg -i apt_1.9.4ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 193526 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_1.9.4ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (1.9.4ubuntu0.1) over (1.9.4ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libgnutls30 (>= 3.6.6); however:
  Package libgnutls30:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

The second dependency (libnutls30) had other dependencies that I also tried to install manually.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libgnutls30_3.6.15-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 193526 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libgnutls30_3.6.15-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgnutls30:amd64 (3.6.15-4ubuntu2) over (3.6.13-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnutls30:amd64:
 libgnutls30:amd64 depends on libhogweed6 (>= 3.4.1~rc1); however:
  Package libhogweed6:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgnutls30:amd64 depends on libnettle8 (>= 3.4.1~rc1); however:
  Package libnettle8 is not installed.
 libgnutls30:amd64 depends on libp11-kit0 (>= 0.23.18.1); however:
  Version of libp11-kit0:amd64 on system is 0.23.15-2.
 libgnutls30:amd64 depends on libtasn1-6 (>= 4.14); however:
  Version of libtasn1-6:amd64 on system is 4.13-3.

dpkg: error processing package libgnutls30:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgnutls30:amd64
```

This appears to have been a huge mistake since now my Package Manager seems to be broken:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-security/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hpcoder1/xUbuntu_19.04/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/dists/stable/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried:

- removing the broken packages using `apt remove`
- installing back the older version of apt (apt_1.8.3)
- running `apt --fix-broken install`
- `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade` (gives other unmet dependencies)
- the answers in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952853/how-can-i-fix-my-broken-package-manager-software-index-is-broken)
- the solutions to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Why bother? There are no updates for that release (19.04/Disco) for apt to find anyway, and the release-upgrade window closed over a year ago. We no longer answer questions about that release. The recommended method at this point is to install a supported release of Ubuntu. 20.04 might be a wise choice -- it's supported for five years.

Comment: Use "LTS" releases - "long time support" is nice as you do not need to tinker with anything while it lasts. Note that the very hardest packages to "tinker with" in a Ubuntu release is `apt` / `apt-get` and `Python` - apt depends on the actual Python version that is present, and package management fails miserably as soon as you touch either apt or Python. Without really knowing myself, I'd still say you would have to know exactly what you're doing to not fail here.